# Start docker-machine On Boot

Tags: macos, docker, launchd

I have a `docker-machine` called `default`. I am trying to get it to start upon boot. I can do it upon log in but I need it without having to log in.

I have put the following file in both `/LaunchAgents/com.docker.machine.default.plist` and `/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.machine.default.plist`, both of which aren't working.

**/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.machine.default.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
        <dict>
            <key>PATH</key>
            <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin</string>
        </dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.docker.machine.default</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/bin/docker-machine</string>
            <string>start</string>
            <string>default</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I have also run `sudo chmod 640` on both files in case there was a permission issue as described [here](http://marenkay.com/posts/2016-01-06-docker-osx/).

When I run, `sudo launchctl load -w com.docker.machine.default.plist` as described in the tutorial I get "service already loaded".

The service is definitely not running as I have checked using `docker-machine ls` and `docker-machine status default` and the machine is stopped on start up.

**Update**

I have added logging into my LaunchDaemon and get the following output.

> Host does not exist: "default"

I then run `docker-machine ls` and I get:

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Stopped                 Unknown
```

As you can see the machine is there. If I run `docker-machine start default` manually, it starts up fine...

```
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Machine "default" was started.
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
```

Comment: Have you checked [this plist](https://gist.github.com/andystanton/257fab335b242bc2658b)? You also need to evaluate current machine IP by running `eval $(docker-machine env default)` bash command.

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov please see original question. Have added my plist file. IPs are fine. The docker-machine isn't even started

Comment: Why don't you use docker 4 mac instead of VirtualBox? The host will always be up when you log in since the mac itself is the host.

Comment: That's the issue. I need it up before log in. It is not possible to start an app before log in.

Comment: Since you tagged this as OSX - have you tried just using [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/) or did you specifically need to use Toolbox?  Recently migrated to Docker for Mac and services / terminal are automatically setup on startup to work directly with Docker. No more explicitly enabling / disabling required. Suggestion only - appreciate it does not answer your specific question.. :)

Comment: I have used this and have actually gone back to it. One of the requirements was to start docker on boot, without any log in. Could not get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Services from /Library/LaunchDaemons by default run as root user. root have no any docker machines. You can specify user (jenkins in my case) as

```
<key>UserName</key>
<string>jenkins</string>
```

For more documentation you can use `man launchd.plist`.

Full org.vovkasm.docker-machine.plist that I'am use for jenkins user:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.vovkasm.docker-machine</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/docker-machine/bin/docker-machine</string>
        <string>start</string>
        <string>default</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>jenkins</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```